# on click event not being bound for content that is dynamically loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

this imy first time I've used Stackflow so please let me know if you need any further information. I have looked at similart questions but can't see a solution.

I have a script in the head section of my main page:

```js
<script>
  $(function() 
    {
  $('#my_ajax_container').load('./user_landing/index.php');

  $("#div_new_case").on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
    alert ("hi");// code
  });

  $.getScript("js/my_data_table/my_data_table.js");
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="div_new_case" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <button id="btn_new_case">New Case</button>
</div>
```

The script:
1. Successfully loads some content (i.e. a jquery data table plugin and a button) into my div id 'my_ajax_container'.

2. It **unsuccessfully** tries to attach an event to the button that is clicked
3. It successfully loads another script which uses ajax to populate the jquery data table plugin.

If I remove the 1st line of the script (i.e. the .load statment) and, instead, simply include the user_landing/index.php file using the PHP include statement in the html body then the event is attached successfully.

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong. Many thanks

Comment: If an answer is correct, you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of binding the event, element with id `div_new_case` was also not present. Hence, you need to bind the event to parent available at the time of binding. Hence, you need to update your code from

```
$("#div_new_case").on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
    alert ("hi");// code
  });
```

to

```
$("#my_ajax_container").on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
    alert ("hi");// code
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally bind the event to the body tag, because it is highly unlikely to not be there after the initial request :)

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
   alert ("hi");// code
 });
```

This is essentially placing an event watcher on the body tag and says "Whenever the #btn_new_case selector is clicked, run the event." So this will work whether you add the element during initial page response, or add elements to the DOM dynamically after.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, `#div_new_case` does not exist yet. Therefore, replace:

```
 $("#div_new_case").on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
    alert ("hi");// code
 });
```

With:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_new_case", function() { 
   alert ("hi");// code
});
```

**Alternatively change your code to:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_ajax_container').load('./user_landing/index.php', function() {;
        $("#btn_new_case").on("click", function() { 
            alert ("hi");// code
        });
        //since this script also needs the content just loaded
        //this may be the best place to load it although it may 
        //work in it's current location
        $.getScript("js/my_data_table/my_data_table.js");
    });
});
```